# I don't need packages dojo and dijit in my cross-domain build

Tags: javascript, build, dojo

Following the instructions from http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/, I have been able to create my own custom build.
However, in the dist folder, there are always the dojo and dijit folder beside my app folder. I don't need these and I will serve the content of these two packages from Google CDN.

How would I achieve this without either manually or programmatically deleting them after each build?

Here's my dojoConfig.js

```
var dojoConfig = {
    ....
    useXDomain: true,
    xdWaitSeconds: 10,
    async: true,
    tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
    packages: [
        {name:'dojo',location:'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/'},
        {name:'dijit',location:'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/'},
        'dojotut'
    ],
    parseOnLoad: true,
    deps: [ 'dojo/ready', 'dojo/parser', 'dojotut' ],
        callback: function (ready, parser, dojotut) {
    dojotut.init();
    }
};
```

Best regards!

Comment: Hi, did you work out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you'Re using dojop from CDN you don't need a custom build at all. Main reason for custom builds is to embed your code with the dojo files according to the defined layers in the build configuration made within your profile file (according to tutorial: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/build/)

In fact what the dojo build system does is resolve require and define dependencies, group them according to the layers, write them into one file (e.g. modules layered with dojo/text will be added to the dojo/text output file), and minify afterwards.

That doesn't remove the single files as they may be required as well but requiring dojo at the beginning loads all embedded modules as well within just ONE HTTP get for example. Thats reducing latency a lot.

My proposal would be if you just want to distribute your app:

Use the dojo CDN
Copy all your app code together into one minified file (e.g. by using grunt) and load that file as well, resulting in almost as few GET from the browser.